# jquery getting correct ascii character from keyInput

Tags: jquery, keydown, numpad

I am trying to restrict the user input to ascii characters. It works on regular keypad, but doesn't work when I press keys on numeric keypad. I tried `event.keycode` and `event.which` both result the same. How do I get the correct code? Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/rg85Y/1/

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="validateMe" type="text" />
</body>​
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$("#validateMe").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Allow only permitted chars
            var chr = String.fromCharCode( event.keyCode );
            alert(chr);
            if( !(/^[a-zA-Z\s'-]*$/.test(chr)) ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
});​
```

Comment: If not included, here are ascii codes for numeric keyboard Numbpad 0 96 
Numbpad 1 97
Numbpad 2 98
Numbpad 3 99
Numbpad 4 100
Numbpad 5 101
Numbpad 6 102
Numbpad 7 103
Numbpad 8 104
Numbpad 9 105 
Multiply 106
Add 107
Enter 13
Subtract 109
Decimal 110
Divide 111

Comment: Sure I can see that in debugger, but how do I get the ascii code for number 0 from numericpad keycode?